# Java Radix sort on 2D Array

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, big-o, radix-sort

[Picture of the Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ThJM.png)

Hello!
I am stuck on this problem where I must sort multi-digit integers (with n total digits) in O(n) time. I believe radix sort is most likely the way to go here, but I am unsure how to properly go about doing that. First I attempted a selection sort but that did not pass any of the tests from the test code.

Here is the code with all of the test cases:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Lab4
{
    /**
     *  Problem: Sort multi-digit integers (with n total digits) in O(n) time.
     *  (Technically, it is O(n * b) time. However, since our base b = 128 is constant, it is O(n).)
     */
    private static void problem(byte[][] arr)
    {  
      // Implement me!      
      for (int i=0; i<arr.length; i++){ //loop rows?
            for(int j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++){ //loop columns?
                  
                  }
            }
              
      
        
    }

    // ---------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Do not change any of the code below!

    private static final int LabNo = 4;
    private static final String quarter = "Fall 2020";
    private static final Random rng = new Random(654321);

    private static boolean testProblem(byte[][] testCase)
    {
        byte[][] numbersCopy = new byte[testCase.length][];

        // Create copy.
        for (int i = 0; i < testCase.length; i++)
        {
            numbersCopy[i] = testCase[i].clone();
        }

        // Sort
        problem(testCase);
        Arrays.sort(numbersCopy, new numberComparator());

        // Compare if both equal
        if (testCase.length != numbersCopy.length)
        {
            return false;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < testCase.length; i++)
        {
            if (testCase[i].length != numbersCopy[i].length)
            {
                return false;
            }

            for (int j = 0; j < testCase[i].length; j++)
            {
                if (testCase[i][j] != numbersCopy[i][j])
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    // Very bad way of sorting.
    private static class numberComparator implements Comparator<byte[]>
    {
        @Override
        public int compare(byte[] n1, byte[] n2)
        {
            // Ensure equal length
            if (n1.length < n2.length)
            {
                byte[] tmp = new byte[n2.length];
                for (int i = 0; i < n1.length; i++)
                {
                    tmp[i] = n1[i];
                }
                n1 = tmp;
            }

            if (n1.length > n2.length)
            {
                byte[] tmp = new byte[n1.length];
                for (int i = 0; i < n2.length; i++)
                {
                    tmp[i] = n2[i];
                }
                n2 = tmp;
            }

            // Compare digit by digit.
            for (int i = n1.length - 1; i >=0; i--)
            {
                if (n1[i] < n2[i]) return -1;
                if (n1[i] > n2[i]) return 1;
            }

            return 0;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        System.out.println("CS 302 -- " + quarter + " -- Lab " + LabNo);
        testProblems();
    }

    private static void testProblems()
    {
        int noOfLines = 10000;

        System.out.println("-- -- -- -- --");
        System.out.println(noOfLines + " test cases.");

        boolean passedAll = true;

        for (int i = 1; i <= noOfLines; i++)
        {
            byte[][] testCase =  createTestCase(i);

            boolean passed = false;
            boolean exce = false;

            try
            {
                passed = testProblem(testCase);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                passed = false;
                exce = true;
            }

            if (!passed)
            {
                System.out.println("Test " + i + " failed!" + (exce ? " (Exception)" : ""));
                passedAll = false;

                break;
            }
        }

        if (passedAll)
        {
            System.out.println("All test passed.");
        }

    }

    private static byte[][] createTestCase(int testNo)
    {
        int maxSize = Math.min(100, testNo) + 5;
        int size = rng.nextInt(maxSize) + 5;

        byte[][] numbers = new byte[size][];

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            int digits = rng.nextInt(maxSize) + 1;
            numbers[i] = new byte[digits];

            for (int j = 0; j < digits - 1; j++)
            {
                numbers[i][j] = (byte)rng.nextInt(128);
            }

            // Ensures that the most significant digit is not 0.
            numbers[i][digits - 1] = (byte)(rng.nextInt(127) + 1);
        }

        return numbers;
    }

}
```

Comment: I don't see any code for radix sort in `problem()`. The numbers are stored least significant digit first, with the first significant digit guaranteed not to be zero, which may be why your selection sort failed. This will also help with radix sort.

Comment: Follow up, since the numbers are stored least significant "digit" first, then a conventional least significant digit first radix sort would start with arr[][0], the next pass on arr[][1], ... . Anything beyond the end of a sub-array would be treated as a digit == 0.